# Prove that if $S$ is a subspace of an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$, then that $dim(S) ≤ n$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Proposition

> Let $S$ be a subspace of an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$. Prove
>   that $dim(S) ≤ n$.

My attempt:

We prove by contradiction.

Suppose $S$ is a subspace and $dim(S) > n$. Let $dim(S) = m$.

Consider arbitrary vectors $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{v}_m$ that form a basis for $S$. We know that basis vectors are linearly independent.

Since $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{v}_m$ $\in S$ and $S \subseteq V$ it follows that $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{v}_m \in V$. And we know that $dim(V) = n$, which means that if we have arbitrary vectors in $V$ $$\mathbf{u}_1,\mathbf{u}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{u}_j $$

where $j > n$, then vectors will be linearly dependent. And since $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{v}_m \in V$  and $m > n$, vectors $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{v}_m$ must be linearly dependent. But this is a contradiction, since we've specified that they form a basis for $S$, and therefore they *must* be independent. Hence our premise must be wrong, and $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{v}_m$ do not form a basis for $S$. $\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it seems good enough.

Comment: How do you know that $S$ is finite-dimensional?